# Assignment of code block into Val

Tags: scala

I am having hard time understanding this syntax,

```
val grid = {
  val input = """ 08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
                |49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
                |81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
                |52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
                |22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
                |24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
                |32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
                |67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
                |24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
                |21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
                |78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
                |16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
                |86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
                |19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
                |04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
                |88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
                |04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
                |20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
                |20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
                |01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48 """
                .stripMargin
  val rows = input.split("\n").map(_.trim)
  rows.map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt))
}
```

Here `grid` is of type `Array[Array[Int]]`> I understand that we are creating a 2D array based on some logic inside `{}` of `grid`. But what is this `val grid = {}`, and how can we do calculations inside of it.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title to something like: `Scala - assignment of code block into val` or something of that sort, as this is a (good!) question regarding this syntax and isn't at all specific to arrays, multidimensional or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, everything is an expression, and you can combine any sequence of expressions at basically any position in the program.

So here, we assign something to `grid`, that something is the content of the `{}` block expression. You can have arbitrary sequences of expressions in a block expression, so in your example we start by definining two `val`, mostly to make the code easier to read.

Then the last expression, which perform a `map` on the previously defined `rows` is the expression returned by the block. That is the value that will be assigned to `grid`.

A good reason to do such a thing here, is that both `input` and `rows` are only visible in the block where they are defined. That means they will not be polluting the scope where you use `grid`. It's actually very good style.

Answer (score 2):

As method declarations (`def`) are allowed to have a [Block Expression](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#blocks) defined to them, so does a [Value Declaration](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions).

If we look into the specification (6.11) under "Block", we can see the definition for a valid block declaration:

> A block expression `{ s1; ……; sn; e}` is constructed from a sequence
>   of block statements `s1,…,sn` and a final expression e. The
>   statement sequence may not contain two definitions or declarations
>   that bind the same name in the same namespace. The final expression
>   can be omitted, in which case the unit value `()` is assumed.
>
> The expected type of the final expression `e` is the expected type of
>   the block. The expected type of all preceding statements is undefined.

And then goes to specify the definition for a value block declaration:

> - A locally defined value definition `val x: T = e` is bound by the
>     existential clause `val x: T`
>
> Evaluation of the block entails evaluation of its *statement sequence*,
>   followed by an evaluation of the final expression `e`, which defines
>   the *result of the block*.

This shows that block expression is valid for member declaration as well as for methods. This is particularly useful when you have a block of code which is relevant only to the initialization of the member, allowing you to create a more complex initialization sequence.